# Need to upate data in table from data in another

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have two tables and need to update ClientInfo with ServiceLocation information from EligibleServices table

```
**Table: EligibleServices**   

ChartNumber
-----------
1
2
3    

ServiceLocation
---------------
Office1
Office2
Office3

**Table: ClientInfo**

Chartnumber
-----------
1
2
3

ServiceLocation
---------------
```

Comment: I'm not an expert, but I believe this can be done with mysql triggers. anyways, storing the same data in the database more than once means that your database is not normalized.

Comment: I am first trying to update database tables then I can normalize was all tables are updated.

Comment: If I understand this question correctly, this is a really simple update statement. Show what you've tried (this might also clear things up about what you want to do), please. Otherwise this question will get closed. Quoting closing reason: "Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results."

Answer (score 1):

You can do an `update` with a `join`:

```
update clientinfo ci join
       eligibleservices es
       on ci.ChartNumber = es.ChartNumber
    set ci.ServiceLocation = es.ServiceLocation;
```